# perspective view of a rectangular label pasted on cylindrical surface

Tags: transformation, projection, perspective, cylindrical

Have a look at this image.
[image: an object exacted from a cylindrical surface]

This is the edge of **perspective projection result of a rectangle region on a cylindrical surface** (like a bottle). The rectangle's vertical median line is parallel with the axis of the cylindrical surface.

I know how to do perspective tranformation of quadrangle on a plane (http://alumni.media.mit.edu/~cwren/interpolator/ and [Perspective Transform in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20261228/perspective-transform-in-matlab)), but how to do it on a cylindrical surface?
what I want is to transform the region to the original rectangle.

My problem is almost like this: [Unwarp curved surface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23240141/unwarp-curved-surface)

thanks for help!

---

here is a simple explaination in two images. I rolled image 1 and pasted it on a bottle, then I took a picture from some distance with a specific angle and orientation. Then how can I restore Image 1 from Image 2?
[image]
Image 1
[image]
Image 2

Comment: What _exactly_ do you want to do? and please, don't answer in a comment but rather edit your question.

Comment: @gboffi sorry, but i've added some more description.

Comment: I have an answer ready if what you want, using the bottle analogy, is drawing on the label (the label being a planar rectangle!) of the bottle and then obtain a perspective view of what you've drawn on the label. Can you confirm my supposition?

Comment: @gboffi I've added 2 pictures to make the question easy to understand. what i already get is a perspective view and i wanna transform it to its orignal shape. sorry, but my last reply should not be "yes" :(

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to know what the OP really wants from the question that was posed.

If s/he wants to draw a polyline on the label of the bottle, a bottle of radius `r`, and then draw the same polyline in a generical perspective view, the idea is to first unfold the label to a plane, you can do it as a cylindrical surface  is developable, then

1. draw said polyline in plane `x*-z'` with `y'=y0=r`

fold back the label over the bottle surface

2. map the polyline on a cylinder with axis `x'=0, y'=0`

   ```
   z' = z'
   angle = x*/y0
   y' = y0*cos(angle)
   x' = y0*sin(angle)
   ```

go back to global coordinates

3. apply a generic change of coordinates (rotation+translation)

given your point of view, etc

4. project perspectically

Note that horizontal lines on the label are curved lines in Cartesian coordinates, so a straight line has to be subdivided in a number of segments to be rendered with sufficient accuracy.